# Why is `boost::hana::range_c` not a Sequence?

Tags: c++, boost-hana

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename ...T>
void indexed_T_work(T&& ...args)
{
    auto indices = hana::range_c<std::size_t, 0, sizeof...(T)>;
    auto types = hana::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    hana::for_each(
        hana::zip(indices, types)
      , [](auto&& pair_) { /* Do index-dependent work with each `T` */ }
        );
}

int main()
{
    indexed_T_work(5, 13, std::vector<std::string>{}, 32.f, 42, "foo");
}
```

I'd like to use `hana::zip` on a `hana::tuple` and `hana::range_c`, but `hana::range_c` is not considered a *Sequence*, which is a requirement for `hana::zip`.  What is the reasoning behind this decision?  How can I (idiomatically) accomplish my goal while respecting that decision?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, there are several solutions:

**Solution 1**

```
auto indices = hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>(hana::range_c<std::size_t, 0, sizeof...(T)>);
auto types = hana::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(args)...);
hana::for_each(hana::zip(indices, types), hana::fuse([](auto i, auto&& x) {
    // ...
}));
```

**Solution 2**

```
auto indices = hana::range_c<std::size_t, 0, sizeof...(T)>;
auto types = hana::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(args)...);
hana::for_each(indices, [&](auto i) {
    auto& x = types[i];
    // ...
});
```

**Solution 3**

```
auto types = hana::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(args)...);
hana::size_c<sizeof...(T)>.times.with_index([&](auto i) {
    auto& x = types[i];
    // ...
});
```

Solution **(1)** has the disadvantage of making a copy of each `args` because `zip` returns a sequence of sequences, and everything in Hana is by value. Since this is probably not what you want, you should pick whichever you prefer between solutions **(2)** and **(3)**, which are really equivalent.

Now, the reason why `range`s do not model the `Sequence` concept is because that wouldn't make sense. The `Sequence` concept requires that we be able to create an arbitrary `Sequence` using the `hana::make` function. Hence, for any `Sequence` tag `S`, `hana::make<S>(...)` must create a `Sequence` of tag `S` that contains `...`. However, a `range` must contain contiguous `integral_constant`s in some interval. Hence, if `range` was a `Sequence`, `hana::make<hana::range_tag>(...)` should contain whatever `...` is, which breaks the invariant of a `range` if `...` are not contiguous `integral_constant`s. Consider for example

```
hana::make<hana::range_tag>(hana::int_c<8>, hana::int_c<3>,
                            hana::int_c<5>, hana::int_c<10>)
```

This should be a `range` containing `integral_constant`s `8,3,5,10`, which does not make sense. Another similar example showing why a `range` can't be a `Sequence` is the `permutations` algorithm. The `permutations` algorithm takes a `Sequence` and returns a `Sequence` of `Sequence`s containing all the permutations. Clearly, since a `range` can only hold `integral_constant`s, it does not make sense to try and create a `range` of `range`s. Examples like this abound.

In other words, `range`s are too specialized to model the `Sequence` concept. The upside of having such a specialized structure is that it's very compile-time efficient. The downside is that it's not a general-purpose container and some operations can't be done on it (like `zip`). However, you can totally take a `range` and convert it to a full-blown sequence, if you know what the tradeoff is.